# How to make a windows computer "know" a printer by network name, not by IP address?

Tags: windows-7, printer

How can a windows (7) computer have a printer which is on the network, installed **as a local printer** in a way that even if the IP address is dynamic and will change, the printer will still work without further setup?

EDIT: the printer is attached via a wireless network; also, when I add it by name (using the windows GUI), it still internally uses the IP (as can be seen in the printer properties and the like), but I want to use the name, because ip changes by dhcp break it.

Comment: The answer is in your question title. It has a name.

Comment: Is the printer attached through a computer, or to the network directly? The model name would be useful too.

Comment: Ok, after re reading your question, I may have my answer wrong.... Unless you have a rubbish printer with horrible drivers, there should be no difference what so ever between a local printer and a network printer other than on the `port` page, it will target an ip address instead of a local USB/lpt/com socket.

Answer (score 1):

Check your printer's manual on how to print out its network configuration page.  That page will show your the printer's hostname.  The hostname remains constant, even if its address changes via DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on the resources you have at your disposal, so I will give a few answers.

In all honesty, you shouldn't be having this sort of problem, I saw a client that had 30 printers on his machine as he had a dodgy DHCP router and it kept dishing out new addresses.

Based on the fact that you said the same name, I am guessing it will be the same printer, please correct me if I am wrong.

First and quickest option, You may want to look at a static IP. This will completely stop the need for updating the IP address.

Next way which will accomplish your goal is to have a proper DNS/DHCP set up (with low TTLs). I still think the previous suggestion is better, but, if it does update the IP, at least the DNS entry will be fresh. Also if you have to use DHCP, consider using MAC reservations for devices that will be permanent/there for a long time.

Another suggestion for now is to use your hosts file. If you create an entry for `x.x.x.x printer`, you should be able to set up `printer` as the printer, then just update the ip here. You may need to flush your DNS ((elevated)`Command Prompt` > `ipconfig /flushdns`) fpr the settings to be applied.

Lastly, and this isn't really what you want, but I have to throw it in - if you are willing to update the hosts file, why not just update the IP of the printer in the printer settings page.